# PHP array_diff for comparing 2 arrays with different length?

Tags: php, arrays, string-comparison, array-difference

I used array_diff to compare to 2 strings converted into arrays by explode, it can compare 2 arrays of the same length, how I accomplish comparing arrays of different length?

Ex.
Array1: The quisck browsn fosx
Array2: The quick brown fox
Works!!

Array1: The quisck browsn
Array2: The quick brown fox
Doesn't Work!!(fox was not mentioned)

```
<?php
$str1 = "The quisck browsn";
$str2 = "The quick brown fox";
$tempArr;
$var2;
$ctr=0;

echo "Array1:<br> $str1 <br><br>Array2:<br> $str2";

$strarr = (explode(" ",$str1));
echo("<br>");

$strarr2 = (explode(" ",$str2));
echo("<br>");

$result = array_diff($strarr,$strarr2);
//print_r($result);

if (count($result) > 0){
    echo "<br>Differences: | " ;
    foreach ($result AS $result){
        echo $result." | ";
    }
 }
```

Comment: `array_diff` can handle arrays of different lengths just fine.

Comment: sir if you run my code you will see that array_diff ignored the last value of Array2 which is fox. May I ask if what part of my code could have been the reason for this if not array_diff?

Comment: What you may be missing is that `array_diff` *"returns an array containing all the entries __from `array1`__ that are not present in any of the other arrays."* http://php.net/array_diff

Comment: so what your saying is if I switch the value of array1 to those of array2 the value fox will be considered as difference?

Comment: Yes. The "total" difference of both arrays is `array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a))`. Or alternatively, take the *intersection* of both arrays and remove it from the union of both (`array_diff(array_merge($a, $b), array_intersect($a, $b))`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$str1 = "The quisck browsn";
$str2 = "The quick brown fox";
$tempArr;
$var2;
$ctr=0;

$strarr = (explode(" ",$str1));
echo("<br>");

$strarr2 = (explode(" ",$str2));
echo("<br>");

if(sizeof($strarr) > sizeof($strarr2)){
    $result = array_diff($strarr,$strarr2);
}else{
    $result = array_diff($strarr2,$strarr);
}
```

The above will return the difference between array size greater than the lower.i.e. element present in first array but not in 2nd.

But if you want the complete difference between 2 of them i.e. element in first array does  not exist in 2nd and vice versa you can do something as

```
$fullDiff = array_merge(array_diff($strarr, $strarr2), array_diff($strarr2, $strarr));
```

Comment: thnx mate I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = "The quisck browsn";
$str2 = "The quick brown fox";
$tempArr;
$var2;
$ctr=0;

echo "Array1:<br> {$str1} <br><br>Array2:<br> {$str2}";

$strarr = (explode(" ",$str2));
echo("<br>");

$strarr2 = (explode(" ",$str1));
echo("<br>");

$result = array_diff($strarr,$strarr2);
//print_r($result);

if (count($result) > 0){
    echo "<br>Differences: | " ;
    foreach ($result AS $result){
        echo $result." | ";
    }
}
```

Use this since it retruns an array containing all the entries from $str2
   that are not present in any of the other arrays.